# How to use SASS / SCSS with latest vue-cli starter project?

Tags: webpack, sass, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to use SASS or SCSS in my project.

I used the vue-cli to make the latest version of a starter project.

Anyone had any success in making sass/scss work in the newest starter project with webpack?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

1. you install the necessary dependencies

   `npm install -D node-sass sass-loader`
2. for global styles, simply import the file into `main.js`:

   `import './styles/my-styles.scss'`
3. in `.vue` files, add the lang to the `<style>` element.

   `<style lang="scss">`

If using webstorm:

`<style lang="scss" rel="stylesheet/scss">`

Comment: 2nd wont work with default project by vue-cli. It is important to expand webpack with rule for sass

Comment: @KirillMatrosov Did you use template from latest [vuejs-templates/webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack). It actually work for me.

Comment: @Illuminator, yes, I am. And I add 'test: /\.scss$/' rule to bundle separrate scss files correctly

Comment: @KirillMatrosov My project just use [`import './scss/main.scss';`](https://github.com/gluons/vue-github-buttons/blob/27be90d6107419ea6f832b3caba5712a53a19f40/src/main.js#L10) in `main.js`. It work fine. I followed [Pre-Processors documentation](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/pre-processors.html).

Comment: @Illuminator, I had error with '@import' to this scss from others. "Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Comment: @KirillMatrosov My project also use [`@import './colors.scss';`](https://github.com/gluons/vue-github-buttons/blob/27be90d6107419ea6f832b3caba5712a53a19f40/src/scss/main.scss#L1). It's weird.  It shoud be great if can you put your project here. 

Comment: that template *does* support this out of the box. I personally use it and work on its development.

Comment: should i have to add `<style lang="scss">` in every `.vue` file ?

Comment: yes. without it, syntax hioghlighting and interoperability between different projects would be impossibl, so providing some kind of "default" setting isn't really a viable solution.

Comment: I am using the RC-3 builds of @vue/cli plugins and getting an error on my single line of SASS which is an import. The error, however, is telling ... it says `Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was 'import "chartist/di'`

[gist](https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/595c20ddfc24854578736e7b8c5caf110

Comment: Your gist is not working, but it seems like you wrote a javascript import statement(`import 'chartist/ ....'`) instead of a SCSS import (`@import '~chartist/...'`)

Comment: What does `-D` stand for?

Comment: @RoCk `-D` stands for dev (as in development) — it lists the specified dependency under `devDependencies` instead of `dependencies` in the `package.json` file. It's the same as using `--save-dev` but it's just shorter to type.

Comment: Is there a way to have the scss being imported without having to include the `style` tag on every vue component? Do anyone knows?

Answer (score 5):

As Latest documentation of `@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0"`, 
first need to install two npm dev dependencies i.e. sass, sass-loader

**Sass**

`npm install -D sass-loader sass`

`yarn add --dev sass-loader sass`

Then you can import the corresponding file types, or use them in *.vue files with:

```
<style lang="scss">
  $color: red;
</style>
```

Refer to [latest documentation here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `package.json` in `scripts` and run

```
"compile:sass": "node-sass 'your main scss file location' 'your compiled css file location' -w"
```

Please make sure that `node-sass` and `sass-loader` are added properly.

And then in you App.vue file add this, then run

```
<style lang="scss">

    @import 'your compiled css file location';

</style>
```

This works for me.

Thanks

Comment: What should be the compiled css file location ?