# How to configure webpack via vue-cli 3 to use sass

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm building a vue app with vue-cli 3.  I'd like to include sass files in my webpack build but the vue-cli abstracts away the `webpack.config.js` file.  Instead we are to create a `vue.config.js` file and configure it with a set of instructions.

If I were configuring `webpack.config.js`, the following would work:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted

      // this will apply to both plain `.scss` files
      // AND `<style lang="scss">` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  // plugin omitted
}
```

How should I configure my `vue.config.js` to achieve the same?  Here is my best attempt:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
            .rule('scss')
            .test(/\.scss$/)
            .use('vue-style-loader')
            .loader('vue-style-loader')
            .use('css-loader')
            .loader('css-loader')
            .use('sass-loader')
            .loader('sass-loader')
            .end();
    }
};
```

This fails with the message

```
ERROR  TypeError: config.module.rule(...).test(...).use(...).loader(...).use is not a function
```

Comment: did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019469/how-to-use-sass-scss-with-latest-vue-cli-starter-project, we also have sass and we have no specifics in vue.config.js for that, you can always run is vue inspect --mode production > production.config.js to see the webpack config the vue-cli uses on npm run build or vue inspect --mode development > development.config.js to see the webpack config the vue-cli uses on npm run serve , if you alter that vue.config file, and run them again you can see your changes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vue cli 3 then just run the following in your project root directory:

```
vue add style-resources-loader
```