# How to properly setup vue.config.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-4

I had following vue.config.js code:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: `@import "@/assets/css/_global.scss";`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I build my Vue project I realized that it's size was huge (2.2MB) and after searching internet I added following code to my vue.config.js:

```
configureWebpack: {
    devtool: false
}
```

Now, my project size decreased to 970kb. Is there more I could do to minify my project? How to setup vue.config.js properly for production mode?

My whole vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: `@import "@/assets/css/_global.scss";`
            }
        }
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: false
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your full `vue.config.js` file look like?

Comment: @MattOestreich The combination of the first code and the second code I provided, nothing more.

Comment: So can you post it in it's entirety?

Comment: @MattOestreich I just added it.

Comment: My concern is I don't think you have to use the `sass` loader like that in `vue.config.js`.. I'm not sure if thats what was bloating your project or not.. I tried to find an old project of mine where I had similar issues, but was unable to locate it.  2.2MB for a Vue project is absolutely massive (not sure what other dependencies you have) - I believe all I had to do was install `node-sass` & `sass-loader` then just import my `sass`/`scss` in my entry point `main.js`/`index.js`.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019469/how-to-use-sass-scss-with-latest-vue-cli-starter-project

Comment: Check out https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/